# windows workflow 4.5: Get all idle workflows

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I am using windows workflow 4.5. I have several stages where I break the flow and persist the information. I Have one service with 3 RecieveAndSend activities. I want to be able to start up a lot of workflows and then I want to to be able to query the persistence database to see all idle workflows and the points at which they are blocked. I would then be able to see the workflows get some correlation number and enter it and then resume that workflow.

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a state machine or flowchart?

Comment: @EricRohlfs I currently have it as a state machine, I was going to look into flowcharts later for future refactors.

Answer (score 1):

From experience, using the persistence database other than to persist/re-hydrate workflows is a pain.
To monitor and record what a workflow is doing (or its persistence state) you use [Workflow Tracking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513992(v=vs.110).aspx)